# Conditional formatting of labels on x axis with dimple

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I have a simple Dimple chart similar to the basic example at:
http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical

The x axis shows dates. Question: how to display the label in eg. red color if the date matches today ?

I tried unsuccesfully:
- to add  tags but this is a no-go since svg's text does not support html
- to change the class name through Dimple or d3.js but no success

Probably the result can be achieved by directly accessing the DOM node and changing the CSS fill style but is there a mode elegant method ?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Conditional formatting for the bars in a chart... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079512/typeerror-undefined-when-adding-conditional-formatting-to-my-bar-chart