# TypeError/Undefined when adding conditional formatting to my bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to my simple bar chart. It's partially working, until I attempt to hover one of the bars, then I get the following error:

`TypeError: c[(this.position + "Field")] is undefined`

Contents of `data.csv`:

```
date,est_sleep,bool_field
2017-11-01,7.5,0
2017-10-31,8,0
2017-10-30,7,1
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
        var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 500, 600);

        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 400, 300)
        myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "date");
        var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "est_sleep");
        var x = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
        x.addOrderRule("date", true);
        myChart.draw();

        svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .style("fill", function(d){
            if(d.bool_field == 1)
                return "#f00";
            else
                return "#99C1DC";
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d){
            if(d.bool_field == 1)
                return "#931D1D";
            else
                return "#98B5C9";
        });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Current results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears because of this string:

```
...
svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data) // <== !!!
...
```

It looks like you rewrite data binding that this library sets under the hood. I did not work with dimple.js, maybe exist the more elegant solution, but I can suggest you this solution:

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
  .style("fill", function(d,i){
    if(data[i].bool_field == 1) // <== get data item by index
      return "#f00";
    else
      return "#99C1DC";
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d,i){
    if(data[i].bool_field == 1) // <== get data item by index
      return "#931D1D";
    else
      return "#98B5C9";
  });
```

You can get appropriate data item by index, without `.data()` method. Look at the hidden code snippet below, it works:

```js
data = d3.csvParse(`date,est_sleep,bool_field
2017-11-01,7.5,0
2017-10-31,8,0
2017-10-30,7,1`);

var svg = window.dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 500, 600);

        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 400, 300)
        myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "date");
        var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "est_sleep");
        var x = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
        x.addOrderRule("date", true);
        
        myChart.draw();

        svg.selectAll('rect')
        .style("fill", function(d,i){
            if(data[i].bool_field == 1)
                return "#f00";
            else
                return "#99C1DC";
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d,i){
            if(data[i].bool_field == 1)
                return "#931D1D";
            else
                return "#98B5C9";
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dimple/2.3.0/dimple.latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just noticed that the tooltip doesn't take on the bar's colour... assuming I have to start dabbling with the .on() closure?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not work with `dimple.js`. If this library does not have a native method for changing tooltip color than you will have to change it on `mouseenter` event.